# Convert Unmanaged package to managed package

Tags: managed-package

How to Convert unmanaged package to managed package in partial copy sandbox and I developed my app in enterprise edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Dev sandbox CANNOT be used to create managed packages for the AppExchange, but CAN be used to build and migrate code, metadata and other customizations to production org.

You need to use Developer Edition orgs which are free, stand-alone orgs, made to develop apps and load them to the AppExchange.

Dev sandboxes are different from Developer Edition Orgs.

[Sign up for a Developer Edition org](http://Sign%20up%20for%20a%20Developer%20Edition%20org)